# Connecting C to mysql

Tags: mysql, c

I am connecting  C to mysql and then creating a database .
My code is:

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <my_global.h> 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{MYSQL *conn;
conn = mysql_init(NULL);
if (conn == NULL) {
  printf("Error %u: %s\n", mysql_errno(conn), mysql_error(conn));
  exit(1);}
if (mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "zetcode", "passwd", NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)
 {printf("Error %u: %s\n", mysql_errno(conn), mysql_error(conn));
  exit(1);}
if (mysql_query(conn, "create database testdb")) {
 printf("Error %u: %s\n", mysql_errno(conn), mysql_error(conn));
  exit(1);
  }
mysql_close(conn);}
```

But i don't have the headers mysql.h and my_global.h
How can i get them??
**Thanks**

Comment: You might want to use postgres.  Mysql has poor support for multi-threading - you can't cancel issued queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have installed the Client....you should be able to just link them? Or at least add the include/libs to your compiler?

http://www.mysql.com/downloads/

Comment: i have download connector-c-6.0.2 but when i setup it nothing change and i can't find anything related to it on my pc.any ideas??

Answer (score 4):

In ubuntu/debian

```
$sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient libmysqlclient-dev
```

in centos/fedora/RHEL

```
$yum install mysql-devel
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the library:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

Answer (score 1):

Insufficient. You need all the files for development. You need the header and proper libraries or you won't get anywhere. So if you are one some linux check out something like libmysql or search on the proposed download pages.